# MacBook with 10.6.8 Snow Leopard freezes after Wi-Fi connection

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi, ipv6

I recently switched service providers and received a new router. My phone and old Windows computer connect fine, but my MacBook freezes (rainbow wheel starts going around forever after about 2 mins of being connected). MacBook connects to Wi-Fi fine at a friend's house.  Another [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/144223/macbook-freezes-when-connected-connecting-to-new-wireless-router) describes something similar being solved by switching off IPv6. However, System Preferences > Network > Wi-Fi > Advanced > Wi-Fi > TCP/IP > IPv6 is set to Automatically and all other options are greyed out. I tried to switch it off via directly entering command into Terminal, but it stayed set to Automatically.

Any suggestions as to why I cannot turn it off? Mac is running on 10.6.8 Snow Leopard.

Comment: What model is your MacBook? Can it be updated past 10.6.8 "Snow Leopard"?

Comment: Can you be more specific than "forever"?  Have you waited five minutes?  Ten?

Comment: What is the Terminal command you used?

Answer (score 2):

Try turning IPv6 off *before* connecting to the Wi-Fi.

Turn the AirPort off, go to System Preferences, Network, AirPort, Advanced, TCP/IP, Configure IPv6: Off. Then turn the AirPort on, and everything should work fine.